# Error while printing variable interpolation in python

Tags: python, variables, interpolation

I am python newbie and facing trouble with variable interpolation concept in python
I have written a method to check the argument but it giving error while printing the line

```
   import re
   import sys
   import os.path

   def CheckArgument(argv) :
     for arg in argv :
      if (re.match('^-a$|^-b$|^-c$',argv) != 1) :
        if os.path.isfile(arg) != 1 :
            print ("file %s doesnot exists", % arg)
                            #above line is giving error
        elif re.match('-help',arg) == 1 :
             print "......."


   CheckArgument(sys.argv)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, `re.match()` returns a *`MatchObject`* instance, not an integer. The expression

```
re.match('^-a$|^-b$|^-c$',argv) != 1
```

will *always* be True. Just use `not`:

```
if not re.match('^-a$|^-b$|^-c$', argv):
```

and:

```
elif re.match('-help', arg):
```

You need to remove the `,` from the print statement; the `%` operator acts on the string on the left hand side, but that does mean there should not be a comma in between:

```
print ("file %s doesnot exists" % arg)
```

It looks as if you are trying to parse command line arguments. You could use the [`argparse` module](http://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html) instead for that.